# What should I do to get the values of a listbox item in wpf c#?

Tags: listbox

I have a few images with some text, I need to get the image path with the relevant text in a listbox.

Browsing google I came across this sample class,

```
public class Img
{
    public Img(string value, Image img) { Str = value; Image = img; }
    public string Str { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Img}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding Str}"/>
                <ContentControl Margin="3" Content="{Binding Image}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

---

```
lstBox.Items.Add(new Img("Value", myImage));
```